# Java concurrently overwrite a primitive with the same value

Tags: java, concurrency

I am currently working on a project, which uses a parallel stream to overwrite a boolean, but only change it to false. I am curious about how this works in Java.

If two requests overwrite the Boolean at the same time(exact same time) with the same value. What would happen?

Comment: So this should fail? `boolean foo = false; foo = false; foo = false;`  But.. you have probably created an thread-unsafe program, unless you update a `volatile` primitive field or use explicit synchronization of some sort.

Comment: Ok let me rephrase my question, what if two requests overwrite the Boolean at the same time(exact same time) with same value. What would happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly same time is not possible. Java Virtual Machines often use the underlying scheduler provided by the OS kernel. Scheduler implements a function s(t) from time to processes that assigns the CPU to a process according to a specific policy (FIFO, SJF, Round Robin, Real Time policies, and so on). In each t, only one process is currently running, others are put in the ready queue unless the dispatcher performs a context switch.